# Getting errors for permission handler even though app doesn't use it when upgrading to target sdk 33

Tags: android, flutter

For complying with the new Google App Store policy of target SDK at least 33, I changed the `build.gradle` to take the following:

```
compileSdkVersion Math.max(flutter.compileSdkVersion, 33)

minSdkVersion Math.max(flutter.minSdkVersion, 21)
targetSdkVersion Math.max(flutter.targetSdkVersion, 33)
```

But I get the following error. The issue with a service called "permissionhandler" isn't something I use within my app. (Though I think other packages like `geolocator` use it internally?)

```
/Users/praveenbhusal/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler_android-9.0.2+1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/permissionhandler/ServiceManager.java:75: warning: [deprecation] queryIntentActivities(Intent,int) in PackageManager has been deprecated
            List<ResolveInfo> callAppsList = pm.queryIntentActivities(callIntent, 0);
                                               ^
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
/Users/praveenbhusal/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/permission_handler_android-9.0.2+1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/permissionhandler/PermissionUtils.java:318: warning: [deprecation] getPackageInfo(String,int) in PackageManager has been deprecated
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
                    ^
1 error
2 warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':permission_handler_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDevDebug failed with exit code 1
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: try deleting build folder, it will clear cached packages

Answer (score 0):

It seems like method is deprecated. Try with deleting build folder and then

1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
3. flutter pub get

Comment: I did this too. Upgraded my Flutter version to the latest stable channel, ran the above commands for package clean and upgrade. Now, besides some code that I'd have to refactor to keep up with some updated packages, there's still issue over one package or another. Now, it's connectivity_plus